# Como pesquisar uma frase literalmente no postgre

Tags: postgresql, full-text

Amigos, preciso de uma ajuda.
Estou tentando pesquisar uma frase literal no postgre. Usei plainto_tsquery, mas ele pesquisa as palavras no texto e não a frase literal como foi digitada. O que me retorna mais registros do que eu quero.
Tentei o phraseto_tsquery, mas ele encontra algumas frases e outras não. O que me retorna menos registros do que eu quero.
Usei o dicionario simple ao invés do portuguese, pois ele retornava Renato e Renata, causando falso positivo nas respostas. Não preciso que ele ignore stop words ou pesquise por fonemas.
Criei um dicionário com as seguintes configurações:

```
create extension sc_texto.unaccent;
alter text search configuration sc_texto.br alter mapping 
for hword, hword_part, word with unaccent, simple;
```

Eu consigo pesquisar sem acentuação e sem misturar Renato com Renata. Tudo ok !!
Mas tem alguns registros que o phraseto não consegue encontrar. Por exemplo
"Supermercado Maria".
Se ele estiver no começo do texto ele encontra, se estiver no fim do texto não.
os textos com mais de 50 mil caracteres tem esse problema. Não sei se atingi algum limite do postgre para pesquisa....
Utilizei indice Gin em um campo tsvector, já preenchido com o to_tsvector da coluna apropriada.
Os textos são gerados de um OCR de jornais e revistas.

Desde já agradeço a atenção.